# Spring MVC + JSON = 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm trying to generate a simple JSON response working. Right now I get 406 Not Acceptable error. Tomcat says "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers." even though my `Accept` headers are

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

In tomcat/lib I have all Tomcat jars, Spring jars and jackson-all-1.9.0.jar. I'm using Spring 3.2.2 with Tomcat 7.

I'm aware that this issue has been discussed many times, but none of solutions is working for me.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.smiechmateusz.controller" />
 <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
package com.smiechmateusz.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

import com.smiechmateusz.dao.Foo;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="foobar.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Foo getShopInJSON() {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.setX(1);
        f.setY(2);
        f.setDescription("desc");
        return f;
    }
}
```

**Foo.java**

```
package com.smiechmateusz.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="foobaz")
public class Foo implements Serializable
{
    private int x, y;
    String description;
    int id;

    @Column(name = "x")
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    @Column(name = "y")
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Column(name = "description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I've already tried adding

```
<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
          <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
          </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

to my **dispatcher-servlet.xml** or changing *jakcson-all* to *jackson-asl* and *jackson-core-asl* but output was the same.

Comment: Can this help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828968/mapping-restful-ajax-requests-to-spring ?

Comment: After doing what's written there I no longer get 406 Error but I don't get JSON response either. In fact, I don't get any response. Server returns empty document with 200 status.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

That should be the problem. JSON is served as `application/json`. If you set the Accept header accordingly, you should get the proper response. (There are browser plugins that let you set headers, I like "Poster" for Firefox best)

Comment: It doesn't change anything, I'm still getting 406 Error.

Comment: @Mateusz you also have to set up spring mvc correctly as alain.janinm writes. The easiest way to do that is through `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or through `@EnableWebMvc`. See [this previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908632#5908632) for a complete working example

Comment: Thank you very much, with your antecedent post I've finally managed to get it working.

Answer (score 39):

If you're using Maven and the latest [Jackson code](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) then you can remove all the Jackson-specific configuration from your spring configuration XML files (you'll still need an annotation-driven tag <mvc:annotation-driven/>) and simply add some Jackson dependencies to your pom.xml file. See below for an example of the dependencies. This worked for me and I'm using:

- Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 01:44:56-0700)
- org.springframework version 3.1.2.RELEASE
- spring-security version 3.1.0.RELEASE.

  ```
  ...<dependencies>
  ...
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      ...
  </dependencies>...
  ```

Comment: @Dharmesh - I would need more information than what you gave me in your comment to help you. Perhaps you can ask a question with complete details, then direct me to that question in your next comment. Good luck!

Comment: I solve the problem.  In my case its very small mistake, I have not provide a getter and setter for 1 field in my Object class because that its give me 406 error when its try to convert my Object in JSON response body using @ResponseBody annotation.

Answer (score 22):

One more way you can get this error is to create a class with no public members. 406 unacceptable is a pretty useless error message in this scenario.

Answer (score 10):

With Spring 4 you only add `@EnableWebMvc`, for example:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
@RequestMapping(value = "/articles/action", headers="Accept=*/*",  produces="application/json")
public class ArticlesController {

}
```

Comment: That fixed it for me. Still kind of trying to figure out why. Seems [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291329/enablewebmvc-annotation-meaning) describes it; if you then have a narrow `@ContextConfiguration` of e.g., only the class under test (for performance reasons), it may not be found normally without `@EnableWebMvc`.

Answer (score 10):

None of the other answers helped me.

I read dozens of Stackoverflow answers about 406 Not Acceptable, HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException, multipart file, ResponseBody, setting Accept headers, produces, consumes etc.

We had Spring 4.2.4 with SpringBoot and Jackson configured in build.gradle:

```xml
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.7"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.7"
```

All routes worked fine in our **other** controllers and we could use GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE. Then I started to add multipart file upload capability and created a new controller. The GET routes work fine but our POST and DELETE didn't. No matter how I tried different solutions from here at SO I just kept getting 406 Not Acceptable.

Then finally I stumbled across this SO answer:
[Spring throwing HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation due to dot in url path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793717/spring-throwing-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-could-not-find-acceptable-r)

Read Raniz's answer and all the comments.

It all boiled down to our @RequestMapping values:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/audio/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="multipart/*")
public AudioFileDto insertAudio(@PathVariable String fileName, @RequestParam("audiofile") MultipartFile audiofile) {

    return audioService.insert(fileName, audiofile);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/audio/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public Boolean deleteAudio(@PathVariable String fileName) {

    return audioService.remove(fileName);
}
```

The `{fileName:.+}` part in a @RequestMapping value caused the 406 Not Acceptable in our case.

Here's the code I added from Raniz's answer:

```java
@Configuration
public class ContentNegotiationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        // Turn off suffix-based content negotiation
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```

**EDIT August 29th 2016:**

We got into trouble using `configurer.favorPathExtension(false)`: static SVG images ceased to load. After analysis, we found that Spring started to send SVG files back to UI with content-type "application/octet-stream" instead of "image/svg+xml". We solved this by sending fileName as a query parameter, like:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/audio", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public Boolean deleteAudio(@RequestParam String fileName) {

    return audioService.remove(fileName);
}
```

We also removed the `configurer.favorPathExtension(false)`. Another way could be to encode fileName in the path but we chose the query parameter method to avoid further side effects.

Answer (score 7):

Use below dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to register the annotation binding for Jackson in your spring-mvc-config.xml, for example :

```
<!-- activates annotation driven binding -->
<mvc:annotation-driven ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect="true" validator="validator">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Then in your controller you can use :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/your_url", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose, that the problem was in usage of ***.htm** extension in RequestMapping (**foobar.htm**). Try to change it to **footer.json** or something else.

The link to the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21236862/537246

P.S.

It is in manner of Spring to do something by default, concerning, that developers know whole API of Spring from A to Z. And then just "406 not acceptable" without any details, and Tomcat's logs are empty!

Answer (score 2):

See the problem is with the extension. Depending upon the extension, spring could figure out the content-type. If your url ends with **.com** then it sends **text/html** as the content-type header. If you want to change this behavior of Spring, please use the below code:

```
@Configuration
@Import(HibernateConfig.class)
@EnableWebMvc
// @EnableAsync()
// @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.azim.web.service.*",  basePackageClasses = { WebSecurityConfig.class }, excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class) })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true).parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(true).useJaf(false)
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Bean(name = "validator")
    public Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

**Here, we are setting favorPathExtension to false and Default Content-type to Application/json.**
**Note:** HibernateConfig class contains all the beans.

Answer (score 2):

Today I too gone through the same issue. In my case, in `web.xml` I have

```
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

my url is having `.html` extension.  Ex:`.../getUsers.html`.  But I am returning JSON data in controller.  .html extension will by default set accept type as html.

So I changed to the following:

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**URL:**

`.../getUsers.json`

Everything is working fine now.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = {"Accept=text/xml, application/json"})
```

on `getShopInJSON()`.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe all fields of your POJO need Getter and Setter.

I fixed it according to this issue.
 reference:[Spring MVC - HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception)

And 406 is not a useful message to fix the bug. You should debug into the codes and see what the Exception is on earth.

Answer (score 1):

this is because of the object is not acceptable at jsp... use his

add this dependency or any other send converted json string to jsp...

for example
add this in pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and use code like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value="foobar.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getShopInJSON() {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.setX(1);
        f.setY(2);
        f.setDescription("desc");
        return new Gson().toJson(f); //converted object into json string
    }//return converted json string
```

Comment: Adding dependency for gson helps to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are trying to produce/recieve json output.
I see two problems with your approach.
1) You didn't specify the application/json in your Accept header
2) You need to specify produces="application/json" in your @RequestMapping

Answer (score 0):

There is another case where this status will be returned: if the Jackson mapper cannot figure out how to serialize your bean. For example, if you have two accessor methods for the same boolean property, `isFoo()` and `getFoo()`.

removed `getFoo()` and put `isFoo()`. it worked for me.

Comment: Yes. This one works for me. @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = {"Accept=text/xml, application/json"})

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see it as an answer here so I thought I would mention that I recieved this error using spring 4.2 when I accidentally removed the getter/setter for the class I was expecting to be returned as Json.

Comment: Yes. This one works for me. Thanks Shubham @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = {"Accept=text/xml, application/json"})

Answer (score 0):

My `RequestMapping` value was ending with **.html** which should be something different.

I tried changing it to **.json** and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the similar issue and resolved by using below code

```
public class ProductList {

    private List<Product> productList =  new ArrayList<Product>();

    @JsonProperty("data")
    @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        return productList;
    }
public void setProductList(List<Product> productList) {
        this.productList = productList;
    }

I am setting ProductList object in ResponseEntity object and returning from controller.
```

Answer (score 0):

My class was annotated with JsonSerialize, and the include parameter was set to `JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT`. This caused Jackson to determine the default values for each bean property. I had a bean property that returned an int. The problem in my case was that the bean getter made a call to a method which has an inferred return type (i.e.: a generic method). For some odd reason this code compiled; it shouldn't have compiled because you cannot use an int for an inferred return type. I changed the 'int' to an 'Integer' for that bean property and I no longer got a 406. The odd thing is, the code now fails to compile if I change the Integer back to an int.

Answer (score 0):

As it is the top answer for this error, I am adding the case for XML here.

There is also a possibility that the object returned hasn't correctly defined XML structure. That was the case for me.

```
public @ResponseBody DataObject getData(
```

Was throwing the same error despite correct headers.
The errors stopped when I added @XmlRootElement to the header of the object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataObject {
    @XmlElement(name = "field", nillable = true)
    protected String field;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case the following was missing from my xxx-servlet.xml config file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

As soon I added this it it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same "406" error, but the root cause is related to Spring's object => json strategy...

Spring: 3.2.2.RELEASE

Tomcat: 7

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/search/v2/{employeeId}")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeProfileResponseData> searchEmployeeV2(@PathVariable String employeeId)
```

EmployeeProfileResponseData.java segment

```
    private Boolean profileActive;

    public Boolean isProfileActive() {
        return this.profileActive;
    }

    public Boolean getProfileActive() {
        return this.profileActive;
    }

    public void setProfileActive(Boolean profileActive) {
        this.profileActive = profileActive;
    }
```

If the poor POJO contains the public method `isProfileActive`, it would always return 406.

But if I removed the method, it returned normal JSON.

So I tried to rename the method as `isMyProfileActive`, then I found the return JSON contained a new attribute:

```
{
    ...
    "profileActive": true,
    "myProfileActive": true
}
```

Then I realised what happened.

When the POJO contained the public method `isProfileActive`, Spring would generate an attribute 'profileActive' accordingly. However, the JSON already contained an attribute with the same name (according to the public getter/setter method). So these two attributes caused a conflict, Tomcat wouldn't return a normal JSON.

That's exactly what a "406" code means.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 406 Not Acceptable client error response code indicates that the server cannot produce a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's proactive content negotiation headers, and that the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.

So finally I removed the `isProfileActive` method, everything fine.

BTW, the `isProfileActive` method is generated by vscode, my colleague pushed that code without too much concern.