# EnableWebMvc annotation meaning

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I read javadoc about `@EnableWebMvc`.

But I don't understand what this annotation mean?

Can you expalin it clearly?

Answer (score 112):

When you're using Java code (as opposed to XML) to configure your Spring application, `@EnableWebMvc` is used to enable Spring MVC. If you're not already familiar with Spring's support for Java configuration, [this is a good place to start](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.0.html#new-java-configuration).

`@EnableWebMvc` is equivalent to `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in XML. It enables support for `@Controller`-annotated classes that use `@RequestMapping` to map incoming requests to a certain method. You can read detailed information about what it configures by default and how to customise the configuration in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config).

Comment: What is mvc:annotation-driven ?

Comment: "It enables support for @Controller-annotated classes", is not correct. From Spring docs, `To enable auto-detection of such @Controller beans, you can add component scanning`

Comment: It is correct. Without `@EnableWebMvc`, a `@Controller` bean is just a bean, not a controller. That applies whether it’s found via component scanning or registered via a `@Bean` method.

Comment: Is this still relevant? We are using mcv approach with spring boot and  @ controller , @ RequestMapping etc. Have never seen @ EnableWebMvc.

Comment: @user3192295 If you're using Spring Boot, it will auto-configure the equivalent of `@EnableWebMvc` for you. Unless you want to switch off all of Boot's opinions about how Spring MVC should be configured, you should not use `@EnableWebMvc` in your application.

Comment: A good explain here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358391/what-is-the-difference-between-using-enablewebmvc-webmvcconfigurer-and-webmvc

Answer (score 60):

Welcome to the world of Spring. There is something you need to understand before you know what the annotation `@EnableWebMVC` means.

Spring traditionally supports two types of configurations:

- [XML based configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/xsd-config.html)
- [Annotation based configuration](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_annotation_based_configuration.htm&ei=RolWUuuSOeKyiAefoYG4DQ&usg=AFQjCNEkCHYdfWVhU78soP0xgVPzgNUZjw)

These annotations are essentially implemented as a part of **MVC Java Config Design**.

Consider a simple class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
}
```

There are no base classes. No spring beans in sight.. Hmmm..

Lets go a little further:

- **What does this actually provide.. ?**

Well, to bore you a little bit more ,it provides a lot a things like:

1. [@MVC request processing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)
2. [Global JSR-303 validator](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/)

and a few more.

Ahahah... But your application works with it right. So, where's the magic.. ?

`@EnableWebMVC <---- What's behind this..?`

This is behind it:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface EnableWebMvc {
}
```

See, now you would think that how pointless using `@EnableWebMVC`. Would you rather:

- Extend [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html)
- Override `@Bean` and other available methods

You can read up on:

- [Java Reflections:Annotations](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html#annotations)

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 3):

When we want to build a Spring Web MVC project we need to add necessary import from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.For that reason, we should use `@EnableWebMvc` in java based configuration. Only one `@Configuration` class may have `@EnableWebMvc`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this annotation to an @Configuration class imports the Spring MVC configuration from WebMvcConfigurationSupport