# How can this code work without @EnableMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this code:

```
package biz.tugay.springJuly18.config;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 18/07/15 Time: 15:09 */

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@SuppressWarnings(value = "unused")
public class MyWebAppInnit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfigClass.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ServletConfigClass.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

and the ServletConfig.class

```
package biz.tugay.springJuly18.config;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 18/07/15 Time: 15:10 */

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "biz.tugay.springJuly18.web")
public class ServletConfigClass {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

and finally a Controller:

```
package biz.tugay.springJuly18.web;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 18/07/15 Time: 12:53 */

import biz.tugay.springJuly18.service.MyService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyWeb {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("message", myService.sayHello());
        mv.setViewName("koko");
        return mv;
    }

}
```

When I deploy this to Tomcat and go to /test I will be redirected to **koko.jsp** . So why does this work without **@EnableWebMvc**?

According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19292026/1173112) it should not?

Here is **RootConfig.java**

```
package biz.tugay.springJuly18.config;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 18/07/15 Time: 15:10 */

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "biz.tugay.springJuly18.service")
public class RootConfigClass {
}
```

Comment: What's in `RootConfigClass`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DispatcherServlet` has two fields

```
/** List of HandlerMappings used by this servlet */
private List<HandlerMapping> handlerMappings;

/** List of HandlerAdapters used by this servlet */
private List<HandlerAdapter> handlerAdapters;
```

whose values decide how a request will be handled (among other things). These fields are initialized and populated with values when the `DispatcherServlet` is initialized by the container. The values come from the context configuration you specify. If your context configuration doesn't provide at least one value of the appropriate type, the `DispatcherServlet` uses some defaults.

These defaults are included in a file named `DispatcherServlet.properties` which is in the same package as `DispatcherServlet`.

For `HandlerMapping`, the values (class names) are

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping=org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,\
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping

org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerAdapter=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,\
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,\
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
```

The javadoc of [`AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html) states

> Implementation of the `HandlerAdapter` interface that maps handler
>   methods based on HTTP paths, HTTP methods and request parameters
>   **expressed through the `RequestMapping` annotation.**

In other words, this implementation also uses methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`.

However, `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is deprecated

> in Spring 3.2 in favor of RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

`@EnabledWebMvc` instead registers a [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html), which is much more sophisticated.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, not using the @EnableWebMvc will lead to using a deprecated object?

Comment: @KorayTugay Yes. (Unless you do what `@EnableWebMvc` does manually, ie. register a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` bean yourself.)

Comment: Great answer thanks.. I will just put the annotation and not worry about this for now..