# Getting org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound error

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-404

I'm getting the 404 error with my first spring mvc application, followed all the configurations but no luck. Can you please help to figure out the problem.

```
    Following is the change:
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HereWeGo</display-name>


    <display-name>HereWeGo</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**HeyThere.java**

```
package com.aditya.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@EnableWebMvc

@Controller

public class HeyThere{

      @RequestMapping("/welcome")
      protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(){
          ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");

          modelandview.addObject("welcomeMessage","Hi user, welcome to the first spring mvc application");

          return modelandview;

      }

}
```

**Hello.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>First Spring MVC Application Demo</h1>
    <h2>${welcomeMessage}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

In the server console i'm getting below warning:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HereWeGo/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

My project name is HereWeGo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks ok, except the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation (which is specific to Java configurations) which does the same as your `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag.(Reference here [EnableWebMvc annotation meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291329/enablewebmvc-annotation-meaning))

Also the fix for this issue, as stated in the comments should be to add
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.aditya.spring" />` the spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml after the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag for registering the controller in the spring application context.

As per your exception, your controller is mapped to /welcome, so you should try
`localhost:<YourServerPort>/<YourWebAppDeployName>/welcome` to entry your controller method and acces your jsp-view.

Comment: Removed specified annotation and accessed with "/welcome", getting same response with following error.


**org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound**

**WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HereWeGo/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'**

Comment: Please try localhost:8080/com.aditya.spring/welcome if 8080 is your server port and let me know if its working

Comment: No luck, one more observation is <localhost>:<port> is also giving 404 page.

Comment: Did your try adding <context:component-scan /> to register your controller bean in the spring context.

Comment: By adding `<context:component-scan base-package="com.aditya.spring" />`  in your spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml after the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag

Comment: Yeah now its working !! I've a query : where we are specifying the jsp file name, how it will detect to which file to take

Comment: The InternalResourceViewResolver is responsible for this issue. You specify your view via your ModelAndView object from your controller(either by constructor as you implemented it, either by setView).