# what is the difference between using @EnableWebMvc + WebMvcConfigurer and WebMvcConfigurer?

Tags: spring

what is the difference between using @EnableWebMvc + WebMvcConfigurer and WebMvcConfigurer??

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcConfig(): WebMvcConfigurer {}
```

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig(): WebMvcConfigurer {}
```

Comment: The first enables web-mvc with defaults, the second relies on the basic settings in the `DispatcherServlet`. If you are using `@EnableWebMvc` in a spring boot application it will disable autoconfiguration for a large part of the web related features.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks deinum! Now I understand.
    can I ask one more question? How to disable tomcat error. I mean.. the error came from Filter like this `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception`
    and I really want to disable the print error!!

Answer (score 5):

```java
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig(): WebMvcConfigurer {}
```

This will only take effect if `@EnableWebMvc` is used. The `WebMvcConfigurer` instancs are detected by an instance of [`DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.html) which is registered through `@EnableWebMvc`. So for this to work you need [`@EnableWebMvc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html).

**NOTE:** When using Spring Boot, this is automatically done when Spring Boot detects Spring MVC classes on the classpath!.

Without `@EnableWebMvc` a `WebMvcConfigurer` doesn't do anything but take up memory. When not using `@EnableWebMvc` the `DispatcherServlet` will install some defaults. Those defaults are hardcoded in the [`DispatcherServlet.properties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.properties) file. Those defaults are hard to modify without the use of `@EnableWebMvc`.

**WARNING:** When using Spring Boot andadding `@EnableWebMvc`, will actually disable a large part of the MVC auto-configuration done by Spring Boot, which can lead to other surprises!