# Why is controller method not returning Object when i add servlet mapping (.htm) to my request on making AJAX call

Tags: ajax, json, spring, web.xml

I am making an ajax call from javascript to my controller and returning an Object.

I am sending `Json` from ajax and retrieving in controller by `@RequestBody` and sending `Json` back from controller using `@ResponseBody`.

My functionality is perfectly working until i had to add .htm in Request mapping.
Now it is  throwing `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` when i am returning same Object(returning just String is working even with .htm).

this is my ajax call from js:

```
var user = new Object();
user.id = 1;
user.name = "Noor";
    $.ajax(contextPath + "/createUser.htm", {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        success: function(result) {
             alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResultDTO createUser(@Valid @RequestBody CitizenUser user){
    log.info("Enter Controller");
    ..
    ..
    ..
    log.infor("Exit");
    return new User(100,"DADA");
}
```

This is perfectly working fine without .htm in mapping.

But my project requires .htm in mapping, so i just cannot remive it.

Can any one help me to fix this issue??

Comment: please mention what version of spring do you use? and json converter api?

Comment: File extension takes precedence over accept headers when determwhich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File extension takes precedence over accept headers when determinating which media type is supported. 
Your `.htm` will force it to be `text/html` and not `application/json`. To disable this you will have to configure the `ContentNegotiationManager` yourself and disable favoring file extensions.

If you use xml you can use the `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` to configure it and pass it as a reference to the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag.

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class=" org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
```

When using Java Config you can use the `ContentNegotiationConfigurer` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
dataType: 'json',
```

you're specifying that you want JSON back in the response. You're effectively setting the request `Accept` header to

```
Accept: application/json
```

So your web application can only respond with `application/json` content. Without the `.htm` extension, there's nothing to restrict the generated response on the server side, so all types are producible, but only the Jackson `HttpMessageConverter` produces `application/json`, so that one will be used .

With the `.htm` extension, you additionally have content negotiation happening. This basically determines what your server should be producing even if it is not acceptable. That's why you get a
`HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`.  If you can't get rid of the extension, look into [`ContentNegotiationConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html) for configuring content negotiation.

See also

- [HTTP Status 406. Spring MVC 4.0, jQuery, JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235472/http-status-406-spring-mvc-4-0-jquery-json)