# Spring mvc servlet-mapping and 406 http core

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, http-status-code-406

I'm working with Spring mvc 4 and glassfish 4 and I had some problems with ajax calls to return object as json, with @ResponseBody. 
Then I found a proper solution [HTTP Status 406. Spring MVC 4.0, jQuery, JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235472/http-status-406-spring-mvc-4-0-jquery-json) that it did not totally work on my project I think because my servlet-mapping.

My servlet mapping was:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

But I want also to serve the request like /* to avoid problems with 406 http code so I've tried this:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

But then the dispatcher also maps the *.jsp and breaks
At the end I've tried this:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

But then the dispatcher maps the *.js and *.css like bootstrap, jquery etc.

And now I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I fix it.
For one side to fix the 406 http code problem I specify the content type from ajax and I remove the *.htm from the controller.

And for the other side I had to fix the servlet-mapping  and add the resource tag to avoid more problems.

Now my servlet-mapping is like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And I add this line to the dispatcher-servlet:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```