# Spring MVC + Jquery + JSON + Ajax status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to hit the url through jquery ajax but I am getting 406 in response.

I tried it through the postman extension through which I have found out that the response header is returning content-type : text/html but to get 200 response code it should be application/json. Please suggest some thing I have given up on this, I have tried everything checked every configuration but didn't find anything wrong. I can see the request is reaching the server getting processed but when the response is returned there is no error on the server side but it show error in the browser console.

Thanks in advance, waiting for the replies.

Method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="adminSectionBySub.html")
public @ResponseBody List<Section> getSectionsBySubjectId( @RequestParam String subjectId) {
    //some code........
}
```

My Ajax call from JSP :

```
    var obj = {
    subjectId : $("#subjectId").val()
}
$.ajax({
    url : "adminSectionBySub.html",
    data : JSON.stringify(obj),
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    success : function(response) {
        alert("success " + response);

    },
    error : function(response) {
        alert("error" + response);
    }
});
```

This is the converter that I have defined:

```
<!--Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: what are you outputing from spring `json` or `text`? try adding a `dataType:"json",` in case of json.

Comment: @Jai tried what you suggested getting the same error. Out put has to be json as I have declared JSON converter

Comment: and what about posting data without stringifying? have you tested that too.

Comment: @Jai Tried that also it gives bad request 400

Comment: what is subjectId? is it a form field like textbox, select, checkbox etc?

Comment: Yes it is a field (drop-down box) in the form and on change event, I am giving an ajax call to the server.

Comment: Got my Answer in this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235472/http-status-406-spring-mvc-4-0-jquery-json?rq=1

Comment: @Jai Thanks for helping me out.