# MappingJackson2XmlView spring 4 MVC

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Why  MappingJackson2XmlView doesn't allow to convert model that contains more than one object ?
see MappingJackson2XmlView.class line 90 :
`throw new IllegalStateException("Model contains more than one object to render, only one is supported");`

Answer (score 1):

This is because there's no default way to convert a list to XML: a document must have [exactly one root element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed). While an unnamed list is a valid thing to return in JSON, it's not OK in XML. You need to specify an [intermediate class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9962380/320036) to hold the list. If you use a `MarshallingView` with a `Jaxb2Marshaller`, you can do this <del>and still offer raw JSON lists</del>:

```
<property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />

        <!-- XML -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                    <property name="packagesToScan" value="example.model" />
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

Here, `example.model.FooCollection` would just contain a list of `example.model.Foo`, and would define its own `@XmlRootElement`.

Comment: Note that you'll probably also need to set up content negotiation as shown in this [question about `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27669568/320036)