# Spring throwing HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation due to dot in url path

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

**Final Edit**

So after researching this because the answer's didn't quite make since with what I was seeing, I found out that Spring does some weird stuff with extension matching. If I submit a request like this `byNameOrAtlName/myStringHere.1` or this `byNameOrAtlName/myStringHere.12` everything is fine, but `byNameOrAtlName/myStringHere.123` causes it to break as does `byNameOrAtlName/myStringHere.com`, but `byNameOrAtlName/myStringHere.co` is ok, but `byNameOrAtlName/myStringHere.c` is not.

In summary, I have no clue what logic spring is using to determine extension stuff, but for certain extensions the `{varName:.+}` works as a sort of work around, but it looks like you need to completely disable dot file suffix to really get around it.

---

Using Spring 4.1.6

Spring is throwing the following exception `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`

I have the following code, and everything works unless the string (name) has a period in it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/")
public class Testing{
    @RequestMapping(value = "byNameOrAltName/{name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Collection<MyDTO> getByNameOrAltNAme(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        return myRepo.getMyDTOsByNameOrAtlName(name);
    }
}
```

So this works. `http://localhost:8080/data/foo/byNameOrAtlName/myStringHere`, but if I do this it fails `http://localhost:8080/data/foo/byNameOrAtlName/myStringHere.fluffy`

I read the other answers around this exception, but none of them seemed to apply to my case. And at first I thought it was the problem where spring doesn't like period to be in the path, and I fixed that before with the regex `.+` but I tried it both with and without the regex and I get the same error.

Any ideas as to why Spring would throw this?

**EDIT**

Here is my debug log:

```
21:32:09,118 DEBUG work.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter: 161 - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
21:32:09,118 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/r2d2/**'
21:32:09,118 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
21:32:09,118 DEBUG y.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository: 192 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@3eda7134: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@3eda7134: REDACTED
21:32:09,122 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
21:32:09,122 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
21:32:09,122 DEBUG ework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter: 128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@518864fd
21:32:09,122 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
21:32:09,122 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/logout'
21:32:09,122 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
21:32:09,122 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 131 - Request 'GET /data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com' doesn't match 'POST /login
21:32:09,122 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
21:32:09,122 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
21:32:09,122 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
21:32:09,122 DEBUG y.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter: 106 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@3eda7134: REDACTED
21:32:09,123 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 324 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/login.html'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/index.html'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/*/css/**'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/*/fonts/**'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/*/img/**'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/*/lib/**'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/*/vendor/**'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/sales/**'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/registration/termsofservice.html'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/registration/privacypolicy.html'
21:32:09,123 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/restaurantui/useractivation.html**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/restaurantui/index.html'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/basicuseractivation/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/orderconfirmation/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/supplieruseractivation/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/restaurantuseractivation/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/useractivation/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/user/passwordresetrequest'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/user/changepasswordfortoken/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/user/checkpasswordtokenvalidity/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/signup/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/downloads/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/unsubscribe.html'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/restaurant/emailsubscriptions/unsubscribe/**'
21:32:09,124 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/adminui/**'
21:32:09,125 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/admin*'
21:32:09,125 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/confirm/**'
21:32:09,125 DEBUG rk.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: 151 - Checking match of request : '/data/restaurant/supplier/bynameoraltname/quill.com'; against '/data/**'
21:32:09,125 DEBUG ity.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor: 218 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116; Attributes: [isAuthenticated()]
21:32:09,125 DEBUG ity.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor: 347 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@3eda7134: REDACTED
21:32:09,126 DEBUG ingframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased:  65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3b97d645, returned: 1
21:32:09,126 DEBUG ity.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor: 242 - Authorization successful
21:32:09,126 DEBUG ity.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor: 255 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
21:32:09,126 DEBUG  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: 309 - /data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com?_=1434072729116 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
21:32:09,126 DEBUG  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: 861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Servlet' processing GET request for [/data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com]
21:32:09,126 DEBUG mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping: 294 - Looking up handler method for path /restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com
21:32:09,127 DEBUG mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping: 299 - Returning handler method [public java.util.Collection<com.siftit.webservices.personae.restaurant.dtos.SupplierDTO> com.siftit.webservices.personae.restaurant.RestaurantSupplierWebService.getByNameOrAltNAme(java.lang.String)]
21:32:09,128 DEBUG k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'restaurantSupplierWebService'
21:32:09,128 DEBUG  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: 947 - Last-Modified value for [/data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com] is: -1
21:32:09,128 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356] for JPA transaction
21:32:09,128 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 367 - Creating new transaction with name [com.siftit.webservices.security.WebServiceInterceptor.preHandle]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
21:32:09,128 DEBUG rg.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils: 153 - Setting JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@624e4a40] read-only
21:32:09,128 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 403 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@6d32e04]
21:32:09,128 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356] for JPA transaction
21:32:09,129 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
21:32:09,129 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356] for JPA transaction
21:32:09,129 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
21:32:09,140 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 755 - Initiating transaction commit
21:32:09,140 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 512 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356]
21:32:09,141 DEBUG rg.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils: 222 - Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@624e4a40]
21:32:09,141 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 605 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
21:32:09,142 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356] for JPA transaction
21:32:09,142 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 367 - Creating new transaction with name [com.siftit.webservices.personae.restaurant.RestaurantSupplierWebService.getByNameOrAltNAme]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
21:32:09,142 DEBUG rg.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils: 153 - Setting JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@624e4a40] read-only
21:32:09,142 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 403 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@32689afc]
21:32:09,143 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356] for JPA transaction
21:32:09,143 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
21:32:09,143 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356] for JPA transaction
21:32:09,143 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
21:32:09,144 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356] for JPA transaction
21:32:09,144 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
21:32:09,144 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356] for JPA transaction
21:32:09,144 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 472 - Participating in existing transaction
21:32:09,146 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 755 - Initiating transaction commit
21:32:09,146 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 512 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1d65b356]
21:32:09,146 DEBUG rg.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils: 222 - Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@624e4a40]
21:32:09,147 DEBUG  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: 605 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
21:32:09,147 DEBUG ethod.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver: 134 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.Collection<com.siftit.webservices.personae.restaurant.dtos.SupplierDTO> com.siftit.webservices.personae.restaurant.RestaurantSupplierWebService.getByNameOrAltNAme(java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
21:32:09,147 DEBUG k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalWebServiceExceptionHandler'
21:32:09,147 DEBUG ethod.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver: 360 - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public java.lang.Object com.siftit.webservices.GlobalWebServiceExceptionHandler.defaultErrorHandler(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception) throws java.lang.Exception
21:32:09,155 DEBUG thod.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor: 163 - Written [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation] as "application/x-msdownload" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@214c8f9d]
21:32:09,155 DEBUG  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:1034 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Servlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
21:32:09,155 DEBUG  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: 996 - Successfully completed request
21:32:09,155 DEBUG ork.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter: 116 - Chain processed normally
21:32:09,155 DEBUG urity.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: 105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
21:32:09,155 DEBUG work.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter: 186 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
21:32:09,156 DEBUG .springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils: 432 - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Here are my request headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=BLABLABLABLA; subscriptionType=PREMIUM; userType=ROLE_ADMIN
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/restaurantui/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Spring is treating the part after the dot as a file suffix to try to determine what response type you actually want. [Here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) is a decent writeup on content negotiation in Spring.

So what happens is that Spring is trying to present the result to in a content type it can't find a converter to.

To solve this you need to tell spring to turn off suffix-based content negotiation:

```
@Configuration
public class ContentNegotiationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        // Turn off suffix-based content negotiation
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I've dug a bit deeper and I think I can explain what's happening.

The default configuration ignores unknown path suffixes, so to explain this we need to know how Spring determines that a path suffix is unknown and that boils down to this piece of code in `PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy`:

```
@Override
protected MediaType handleNoMatch(NativeWebRequest webRequest, String extension)
        throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {

    if (this.useJaf) {
        MediaType jafMediaType = JafMediaTypeFactory.getMediaType("file." + extension);
        if (jafMediaType != null && !MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.equals(jafMediaType)) {
            return jafMediaType;
        }
    }
    if (!this.ignoreUnknownExtensions) {
        throw new HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException(getAllMediaTypes());
    }
    return null;
}
```

So what's happening is likely that the Java Activation Framework is recognising some of your suffixes and returning a media type for them - the *.c* extension probably returns *text/x-c* since that's causing an exception.

Comment: I had this same issue before, and I had fixed it that time using the regex `{varName:.+}`. It turns out my fix is only a sort of fix, and doesn't really solve the problem. I updated my question with the additional information. Your solution should work though. Thanks again

Comment: I've dug a bit deeper and updated with an explanation about what I think is happening

Comment: @Raniz. Thanks.. you made my afternoon. This issue was kicking my butt.

Comment: At last, only this solution worked for me... Thanks for sharing

Comment: This solved my problem as well. I've written a web service which is supposed to accept images via PUT and respond with a JSON blurb which describes the result. I kept hitting the above problem, and since I was only trying to PUT images, it took me quite some time to realise that it was the file extensions which were causing the problems.

Comment: This answer reminded me of a similar issue I had due to file extensions in Spring controller request mappings.  To get around this in both cases I just added a forward slash to the end of the request e.g. `/data/restaurant/supplier/byNameOrAltName/quill.com/`