# Spring Boot Zuul Mulitpart request

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I am working on FileStore application, FileStore is a Spring boot application.

we want didn't to publish the URL of FileStore application,   We wanted to put Zuul application,which will work like proxy.

I tried basic Zuul gateway example. It all works good for normal request following below example

1. https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/

But it fails for mulitpart request. Can anyone have example for support multipart request using Zuul proxy.

We are trying to upload large files via Zuul proxy...

[Exception stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4jDh.jpg)

PreFilter Code:

```
  public class MyPreFilter extends ZuulFilter{

     @Override
      public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
      }

      @Override
      public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

        log.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));

        return null;
      }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: I have added exception and code for PreFilter...

Comment: Do the files have a file suffix? If yes, maybe take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794212

Comment: No, i didn't have file suffix issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use following configuration on zuul API gateway:

```
zuul:
routes:
  user-service-1:
       path: /api/userserv1/**
       url: http://localhost:9090
       strip-prefix: false
  user-service-2:
       path: /api/userserv2/**
       url: http://localhost:9091
       strip-prefix: false 
  user-service-3:
       path: /api/userserv3/**
       url: http://localhost:9092
       strip-prefix: false
```