# Convert the return value of a servlet from JSP to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp

I have a Hibernate project taken from here:
[Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/)

The problem is that the return value calls a JSP page and not displaying the returned string as a JSON.

I've tried putting:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
```

but still it tries calling the JSP page named by the return statement, and not displaying it in the browser (resulting in 404).

How can I change it to return a JSON?

Comment: You need `@ResponseBody` on the method

Comment: It works! Thanks!
But tell me - now if I return an object - instead if "magically" turning it into JSON, my browser return 406 (unable to handle the return value). Why?
It doesn't work even if I move the `ResponseBody` right after the `public` or even if I put on the entity: `@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
@NamedQuery(name = "TestEntity.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM TestEntity a")`

Comment: Adding a request for `org.codehaus.jackson` in maven couses 404

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335591/spring-mvc-json-406-not-acceptable and spring mvc documentation

Comment: Only adding `@EnableWebMvc" did the trick!

Comment: Another quick question - I am now doing a call with `HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");`, and have a string to get it. The server is being called, but the String is null. Why?(Sorry I have many questions...)

Comment: I think you misunderstood how this site is working. If you have many questions, click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and ask for them, this is not some kind of forum

Comment: Just that my questions are connected to one another...