# How to send JSON response from controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

[image]I want to pass a boolean value from my controller to javascript using json but couldnot find a way as I am new to spring mvc.

While using servlet we wrote:

```
response.getWriter().println(somevalue)
```

and the `somevalue` can be received using ajax.
Here my controller method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = REGISTERACTION , method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean RegisterUser(@ModelAttribute("register") Register register,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{

    boolean Registrationsuccess = userService.RegisterUser(register);
    return Registrationsuccess;
}
```

So, here the boolean variable is `Registrationsuccess` which I want to send to js file and receive it using ajax.

And in my javascipt function which is called using **onsubmit** event-->

```
 function AccountExists()
 {
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'registerProcess',
        success: function(data){    
        let detail = JSON.parse(data);
            if( data == true)
                alert("Success");
            else
                alert("Not ");
        }
 });
```

}

Getting error --

The target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.

Comment: Did you try changing the return type to `boolean` and returning `Registrationsuccess` instead of a `ModelAndView`?

Comment: Please check the edit @ Kartik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ResponseEntity` and `@RestController` for JSON Response.

Note : `@RestController` includes both annotations `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.

Try with this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("controller")
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("REGISTERACTION")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> RegisterUser(@ModelAttribute("register") Register register)
    {

       Boolean registrationSuccess = userService.RegisterUser(register);
       return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(registrationSuccess , HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the difference between @ResponseBody annotation and ResponseEntity?@Anish

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal `@RestController` includes both annotations `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal `@ResponseBody` does is it converts the objects to suitable web response like JSON or XML. You can set it. The ResponseEntity is the full HTTP Response . You can set various things in that like status code, content-type and many more.. Please check docs for more info.

Comment: I have edited my question..Can you please Check @Anish

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335591/spring-mvc-json-406-not-acceptable - it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @ResponseBody annotation in your controller's method. And change the return type of the method to Boolean, then return Registrationsuccess instead of ModelAndView.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using 2 approach

**Approach 1:** Set model attribute and using expression language you can find on `jsp`

```
model.addAttribute("test",true);
```

in Jsp page

```
${test}
```

**Approach 2:** If you are sending ajax request instead of  `ModelAndView` create a object
set any attribute `boolean`  and return object from method `@ResponseBody` annotation you will get json in Ajax Response

```
@RequestMapping(value = REGISTERACTION , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody MyCustomObject RegisterUser(@ModelAttribute("register") Register register,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{

    boolean Registrationsuccess = userService.RegisterUser(register);
    MyCustomObject cusobj=new MyCustomObject();
    cusobj.setStatus(true);
    return cusobj;
}
```

Whatever code you have written it will not return json(It is basically form submission approach) so you have to go with first approach.

Comment: I want to send in javascipt function and on the basis of this boolean value i want an alert in my jsp page. @vivekdubey

Comment: I have edited the question..Please Check @vivekdubey

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal using second approach you can do this